# Share Internet through thunderbolt between two Macbook Pros

Tags: vpn, sharing, internet

**WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE**

I have two Macbook Pros (Mojave 10.14.6) with me in a country different than US. A and B. What I need and requirements:

- I want computer B to be connected from a US IP address at all times.
- I cannot install a VPN in B, but I can install anything in computer A,
  including a VPN.

**WHAT I THOUGHT IT COULD BE A SOLUTION AND WHAT I TRIED**

I thought I could make computer B to connect to the Internet through computer A's (through A's VPN) Internet connection so that that if I check computer B's IP address shows the US IP address.

I've been able to share the internet connection from A to B with Thunderbolt 3 cable. However, when I check https://www.whatismyip.com/ within B it shows still the IP as if I was connected to the router in the local region and not the US location.

How can achieve this? Please let me know if you need any clarification.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your internet connection is going through computer A so that's what's assigned the IP by the modem.

Comment: Sorry, but not sure if I understand. When checking computer A's IP address it shows a different one (different country) than the one you would see if connected to the Internet directly without the VPN.

Comment: Sounds like what you're really asking is that the internet connection being shared with computer B is tunneled out via the VPN connection on A, and not just via your local modem connection. I suspect this is going to be down to how the VPN app you have is setup to route network traffic, rather than an OS level question. Which VPN, and how is it configured?

Comment: You could just install the same VPN on B.

Comment: And, it would help if you clarified the question, and what you're really trying to achieve - ie. do you need both computers A and B to both appear on the same IP from your target VPN region? Is just being in that region sufficient (ie. different IPs would be fine). Providing a richer description of what you're trying to do will help everyone provide a better answer.

Comment: Thank you @Alex for your comments. I edited the question with the info. As per the configuration of the VPN (ProtonVPN), here are the different preferences that the app will allow me to change: https://ibb.co/wMp2jDg And here is what it's shown on the Network settings: https://ibb.co/mBb95LT

Comment: Does the address have to be ipv4 or can it be ipv6?

Comment: @DavidAnderson thanks for the comment. The point is to make the computer to look like it is connecting from the US without using a VPN in this computer (B). That is, any connection starts from US ip address. So if anyone checks where this computer is connecting from it has to say it is doing so from US.

Comment: Would you consider a ipv4 to ipv6 tunnel as a vpn? The problem with using a service that would give you access to an ip address from the US is that these ip addresses are known to exist to be for that reason. So you may succeed, but everyone knows you are doing it.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I see. Computer B has a work VPN installed already. How would doing this ipv4 to ipv6 tunnel work? What I really need is that computer B looks like it's connecting from US by anyone that looks at it. Including anyone having access to the computer (company).  Thank you!